# how many linear gradient colors can you use at a time?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use 7 gradient colors as my background every time after the 3rd color it doesn't seem to be working? Can someone give me specific details on what is going on. Code is provided below.

```
body
{
    height: 2500px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#000000 2%,#FFFFFF 2%,#FFFFFF 30%,#2ecc71 30%,#2ecc71 70%,#3498db 70%,#3498db 30%,#000000 30%);                 /* For Safari */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#000000 2%,#FFFFFF 2%,#FFFFFF 30%,#2ecc71 30%,#2ecc71 70%,#3498db 70%,#3498db 30%,#000000 30%);                     /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#000000 2%,#FFFFFF 2%,#FFFFFF 30%,#2ecc71 30%,#2ecc71 70%,#3498db 70%,#3498db 30,#000000 30%);                  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#000000 2%,#FFFFFF 2%,#FFFFFF 30%,#2ecc71 30%,#2ecc71 70%,#3498db 70%,#3498db 30%,#000000 30%);                      /* Standard syntax */
}
```

Comment: @JasonAller nah, why? I'm assuming thats the problem?

Comment: Probably because they overlap each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
body {
  height: 500px;
  background: linear-gradient(
    #000000 0%,
    #FFFFFF 4%,
    #FFFFFF 15%,
    #2ecc71 26%,
    #2ecc71 52%,
    #3498db 78%,
    #3498db 89%,
    #000000 100%);
}
```

which is demonstrated in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t7yS7/). If it meets your needs then you can apply the percentages back to the other lines. I used your numbers and tried to match what I thought you were going for in terms of size.

If you want less fade between colors you can insert the next color with the same percent as the last color. See http://jsfiddle.net/t7yS7/1/ for an example.

@xpy gave me the clue to fix this.

Comment: what does the % mean exactly? I'm assuming the formula to this problem is my number of colors which is 7 divided by 100. Is that correcT? And yes I am using the percentage in term of size.

Comment: The percentage is the distance from origin to place the color. Placing two colors right next to each other at the same percentage causes an abrupt change in color. Placing two colors at different percentages allows them to blend. Rather than 7 divided by 100 I tried to take into account your 2%, 2%, 30%, 30%, 70%, 70%, 30%, 30% to guess how you wanted the colors to appear. Alternatively I could have just changed your last number to 100% and the second to last to a value between 70% and 100%.

Comment: I understand what you're saying but I'm still having the issue in terms of size.

Comment: How do you want the gradient to look?

Comment: I can get the colors on there perfectly fine, but when it comes to breaking them evenly I am having the issue of overlapping I believe

Comment: Can you either link to a jsfiddle showing what you've done or describe how tall you want each color to be?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9678H/ take a look at my code, I am trying to create color bands but I am having trouble creating them after the teal color, ty for your help

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9678H/1/ has comments showing what each color stop is doing in the gradient. I reduced it to 500px just to make it fit better on my screen. If I want to make the French flag I'd do the following: http://jsfiddle.net/V9SdM/1/

Comment: thank you for taking the time to address my problem, you're the greatest! cheers!